# Samples of US Residential or business addresses without zip+4?

Tags: united-states, zip-codes, zip4

I'm looking for a few deliverable residential or business addresses without a zip+4.  By "residential or business", I mean, not a PO box and not military addresses.

According to [this answer on Ask.com](http://www.ask.com/answers/98426321/do-all-valid-us-mailing-addresses-have-a-zip-4-i-e-are-there-some-addresses-that-only-have-a-5-digit-zip-code) (which no longer exists), such addresses do exist, but I'd like to see some samples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work with Address Quality Programs for the National Customer Support Center for the USPS, and looking at our Delivery Point File database, it appears that every residential and business address has an associated ZIP+4s

Comment: Even [unique ZIP codes](http://smartystreets.com/kb/faq/what-how-is-this-a-valid-address), like 12345, [have addresses with a +4 code of "0001" by default](http://smartystreets.com/?input=0001+Default+Plus4+Code+12345).

Answer (score 4):

Coming from SmartyStreets, a licensed USPS CASS™ vendor, I can confirm that Maksim is correct. (From what I've seen -- though I've not looked through the *entire* database!)

The answers you see on Ask.com are not correct. The +4 code is a vital part of the 11-digit DPBC (delivery point barcode), which is comprised of the 5-digit ZIP code, concatenated with the Plus-4 code, concatenated with a 2-digit delivery point, then a check digit.

Since each USPS address has a 12-digit DPBC, each residential/commercial address implicitly has a Plus-4 code.